# Xterm "color query" doesn't print anything

Tags: command-line, terminal, colors

I'm trying to programmatically query the background color of my terminal with

```
echo -ne "\e]11;?\a"
```

but the output appears blank. The issue arises using both Terminal.app and iTerm 3, in both Zsh and Bash, using any number of color schemes. When I redirect the output to a file instead, opening the file in Vi with `vi -u None`, I see the following:

```
^[]11;?^G
```

The value of `TERM` is `xterm-256color`.

What's going on here? How can I get my terminal background color and why isn't the query sequence working?

Comment: The trailing `\`` should be the problem.

Comment: @IporSircer no, that was just a typo writing the post

Comment: Redirecting `echo`'s output does not do what you expect. It literally redirects the exact same string you pass to echo, without it ever hitting the terminal emulator. The intended behavior (as Thomas said, implemented by _some_ terminals) is that you send this to the terminal, and in turn, the terminal responds _as if the user typed the response from the keyboard_, which your app will receive as input. See also xtermcontrol(1).

Comment: Just for reference: the feature request for iTerm is here: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/4953.

Comment: @egmont I was under the impression that it had been developed and merged, but I realize now that it's for v3.2 instead of 3.0.whatever that I have installed.

Comment: Milestone is set to 3.2, this does not necessarily mean it'll be implemented in that version. It's just the current plan of the author.

Answer (score 2):

That's one of several [**`xterm`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) features implemented by *some* other terminals.  Neither of the terminals you mentioned implements this, so far.

Neither is an X application, but this may help:

- [Comparing versions, by counting controls](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#compare_versions)

Comment: This page is a great learning resource. However the real answer is in the comments: "this feature hasn't been released yet", whereas I was under the impression that it had been.

Comment: The cited issue says more than that: it hasn't been **written** yet.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, a feature request exists for this question. I had seen that feature request, but I was under the mistaken impression that the feature was already incorporated into the latest stable release.